# How do I strip a string given a list of unwanted characters? Python

Tags: python, string, strip

Is there a way to pass in a list instead of a char to `str.strip()` in python? I have been doing it this way:

```
unwanted = [c for c in '!@#$%^&*(FGHJKmn']
s = 'FFFFoFob*&%ar**^'
for u in unwanted:
  s = s.strip(u)
print s
```

Desired output, this output is correct but there should be some sort of a more elegant way than how i'm coding it above:

```
oFob*&%ar
```

Comment: You have `F` in your unwanted character list and still have `F` in your output. Is it needed?

Comment: the output listed above is correct. Just that i'm doing it in a not so elegant way

Comment: What is your desired output for `s = 'mKm'`? Does your code compute it correctly?

Comment: it should print a `''` for `s = 'mKm'

Comment: @TimPietzcker, interesting, i get `'K'` as my output, not `'mKm'`, any idea, why's that so? Does strip ignore `len(str)==1`?

Comment: You get `'K'` because you try to strip `K` before you do so for `m`. At that point, nothing happens because the `K` is "shielded" from the stripping by the `m`s around it. (`.strip()` only works from the edges of the string. `"ababa".strip("a")` returns `"bab"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strip and friends take a string representing a set of characters, so you can skip the loop:

```
>>> s = 'FFFFoFob*&%ar**^'
>>> s.strip('!@#$%^&*(FGHJKmn')
'oFob*&%ar'
```

(the downside of this is that things like `fn.rstrip(".png")` seems to work for many filenames, but doesn't really work)

Comment: This doesn't remove characters from the middle of the string; `translate` does.

Comment: No, but the sample code in the question doesn't remove things from the middle of the string either, so I don't think that was the question.

Comment: +1, because I think it actually does what the OP wants, not what his current code does. Kudos to @pts for spotting this.

Answer (score 4):

Since, you are looking to not delete elements from the middle, you can just use.

```
>>> 'FFFFoFob*&%ar**^'.strip('!@#$%^&*(FGHJKmn')
'oFob*&%ar'
```

Otherwise, Use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate).

```
>>> 'FFFFoFob*&%ar**^'.translate(None, '!@#$%^&*(FGHJKmn')
'oobar'
```

Comment: `str.translate()` removes the middle characters, so i could have used a list comprehension of the characters.

Comment: The `strip()` method does your work then, just pass the string as an argument.